# How does security of Imgur API work?

Tags: javascript, imgur

I'm experimenting with [Imgur's API](https://api.imgur.com/) and one thing has got me really puzzled... I want to allow (some of) my users to upload images to imgur and I sorta understand how that works, but I'm wondering about authentication for deleting those images.

Imgur uses oAuth with a token that imgur calls 'Client-ID'... To post an image we would use something like:

```
var token = '...'; // the per-application token
var imgData = '...'; // base64 encoded image data
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
        image: imgData,
        type: 'base64'
    },
    success: function(result) {
        var id = result.data.id;
        window.location = 'https://imgur.com/gallery/' + id;
    }
});
```

(example from [here](https://gist.github.com/eirikb/7404666))

Point is that the authentication token, the Client-ID, is per-application AFAIK... So how to prevent *any* user from deleting another user's image by using the API for delete? E.G. just pasting something like below in their browser dev tool and running it:

```
var token = '...'; // the per-application token
var imageID = '....';  // some id
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image/' + imageID,
    method: 'DELETE',
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // just deleted other user's image??
    }
});
```

Is security implemented on Album level? How does this work?

Comment: Are you _sure_, the token is per-application? Bearer Token auth header is usually used in SSO scenarios (i.e. OAuth 2), where the _user_ is authenticated against the service provider (Imgur)..

Comment: @SebastianS No I'm not sure at all... But I had to register an application with Both Imgur itself and [Mashape](https://www.mashape.com/) and it resulted in a single `Client-ID`... I do see that Imgur has `Account` and `Album` concepts so maybe I have to create an Imgur account for each user... Not sure...